# How to keep relaxed water at start of simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation

Im trying to make a lava sim but as soon as i start the sim the liquid just splashes all over and takes like 2 full secs to settle down. Is there any way to make it settle immediately then react to objects inside the domain. Im trying to have something rise from the lava but simulating is very long since the lava goes all over the place and takes like 5 full seconds to settle down.

Comment: 2 or 5 or too much emotions. I know that feeling :)

Answer (score 2):

**Set *Flow* object to XY dimension of *Domain* at a bottom** so there are not a gaps between Domain boundary and Flow. Like the liquid (Flow) is in a rest shape.

[image]

Note: Previously I thought, liquid explosion can be caused by objects intersecting, but it doesn't matter, even with Effector inside - no movement on a surface before Effector starts to "raise", as you can see in frames 0-30.

[image]